# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'requestContent')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, commerce

I am facing the issue in my react application. 
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'requestContent')**
I am using **commercejs** in my application. The code points to **isEmpty=!cart.line_items.length;**. When checked it shows the proper value. Furthermore, I have noticed that the Api returns NULL array twice and populated array the third time. Why is it so? Anyone there to help me sort this issue?

**Cart.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Typography, Button, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

import useStyles from "./CartStyles";

const Cart = ({ cart }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  console.log("CART ",cart.line_items); 
  const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;

  const EmptyCart = () => {
    <Typography variant="subtitle1">
      You donot have any item in your shopping cart. Start adding some of the
      items in your shopping cart.
    </Typography>;
  };

  const FilledCart = () => {
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        {cart.line_items.map((item) => (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={item.id}>
            <div>{item.name}</div>
          </Grid>
        ))}
        <div className={classes.cartDetails}>
          <Typography variant="h4">
            Subtotal: {cart.subtotal.formatted_With_symbol}
            <div>
              <Button
                className={classes.emptyButton}
                size="large"
                type="button"
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
              >
                Empty Cart
              </Button>
              <Button
                className={classes.checkoutButton}
                size="large"
                type="button"
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
              >
                Checkout
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </>;
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h3">
        Your Shopping Cart
      </Typography>
      {isEmpty ? <EmptyCart /> : <FilledCart />}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import Products from "./components/Products/Products";
// import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";\
import { commerce } from "./lib/commerce";
import { Products, Navbar, Cart } from './components';

const App = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

    const fetchProducts = async() => {
        // call the product api from commerce js
        const { data } = await commerce.products.list();
        // populates the products
        setProducts(data);
    }

    //get element of cart
    const fetchCart = async() => {
        const cartItems = await commerce.cart.retrieve();
        setCart(cartItems);
    }


    const handleAddToCart = async(productId, quantity) => {
        const itemsInCart = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);
        setCart(itemsInCart.cart);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        //Calling of methods which we want to call on load of component
        fetchProducts();
        fetchCart();
    }, []);
    //  empty array is given so that it makes a call as soon as component is loaded.
    console.log(cart);
    return ( <
        div >
        <
        Navbar totalItems = { cart.total_items }
        / >   <
        Cart cart = { cart }
        /> < /
        div >
    );
};

export default App;
```

**Error Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is caused by your initial `cart` state in `App`:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState({});
```

It's an empty object (`{}`) and passed on to the `Cart` component that then assumes it has a `line_items` property.

```
const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;
```

Since `cart.line_items` is undefined an error is thrown when you then attempt to reference the `length` property.

## Solution

Use an Optional Chaining operator to guard the null access.

```
const isEmpty = !cart.line_items?.length;
```

Or guard clause/null check

```
const isEmpty = !(cart.line_items && cart.line_items.length);
```

## Additional

> Furthermore, I have noticed that the Api returns NULL array twice and
> populated array the third time. Why is it so? Anyone there to help me
> sort this issue?

This is likely a combination of the `console.log("CART ",cart.line_items);` in the function component body as an unintentional side-effect and the app being rendered into a `React.StrictMode` component that intentionally double invokes certain functions and component methods twice as a way to help you detect unintentional side-effects.

[Detecting unexpected side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - ***Function component bodies***
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`